# Long int to char: strange output in C

Tags: c, char, long-integer

I have the following char sequence:

```
    char* input = "3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734";
```

Then I try to extract the first two characters from `input` and store it **as numbers** like this:

```
char state_col[9];
char state_col_t[3];

memcpy(state_col, input, 8);
state_col[8] = 0;
state_col_t[0] = state_col[0]; state_col_t[1] = state_col[1]; state_col_t[2] = 0;
long int value = strtol(state_col_t, &endptr, 16);
char c_value = value;
```

When I try to print out the results:

```
printf("%x %x", c_value, value);
```

I get this (for example):

> 32 32
>
> 43 43
>
> fffffff6 f6
>
> ffffffa8 a8

It seems to have something to do with values > 0x80. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether `char` is signed is implementation-defined and how to convert integers that are too large to signed integer is also implementation-defined.

You should use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` for `c_value`.

Note that you will have to include `inttypes.h` (or `stdint.h`) to `uint8_t`.

By the way, you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. Correct format specifier to print data having type `long int` in hexadecimal is `%lx`.

Using `%x` for `char`, `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` should be OK thanks to integer promotion.